# UIScrollview control scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an iOS project which needs to "control" the `UIScrollview's` scrolling. `UIScrollview` needs to know current scroll position, also needs to limit scroll, and "transfer" the scroll to scroll the `UITableView` inside it.

I tried to google, apple dev, ... but no luck :(

I have to handle `UIPanRecognizer` by myself, but it isn't "smooth" like `UIScrollview` default scrolling (scroll accelerator).

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you explain a little more exactly what you mean when you say you want *"to limit scroll"*?  Are you talking about slowing it down?  Are you talking about disabling and enabling scroll dynamically?  And what is this `UITableView` inside it?  Can you show us some of your code, or make a little picture that explains which view is contained in which other view?

Comment: thanks for reply. its a uiscrollview with uitableview+top search bar in it. when i scroll, tableview needs scroll first to show searchbar, then scroll scrollview. and then, searchbar need to be scrolled to hide before scrollview scroll